# Zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated, but my arrays aren't zero-dimensional

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm facing an error when using `np.concatenate`. The code that I'm using is:

```
def get_angles(pos, i, d_model):
    angle_rates = 1 / np.power(10000, (2 * (i // 2)) / np.float32(d_model))
    return pos * angle_rates


def positional_encoding(position, d_model):
    angle_rads = get_angles(np.arange(position)[:, np.newaxis],
                            np.arange(d_model)[np.newaxis, :],
                            d_model)

    sines = tf.math.sin(angle_rads[:, 0::2])
    cosines = tf.math.cos(angle_rads[:, 1::2])

    pos_encoding = np.concatenate([sines, cosines], axis=-1)
    pos_encoding = pos_encoding[np.newaxis, ...]

    return tf.cast(pos_encoding, dtype=tf.float32)
```

The line of code that's causing problems is the `np.concatenate` part in function `positional_encoding`. When the program hits that part it spits out

```
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

but when I check the dimensions for `sines` and `cosines`, they each have dimensions `(50, 25)`.

Is there something that I'm missing when performing these operations?

Thank you.

**Edit**

`position` = 50

`d_model` = 512

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that well tensorflow but might it be because `sines` and `cosines` are `Tensor` objects that have not (yet) be evaluated and `np.concatenate` is a NumPy function that expects regular (ie evaluated) arrays?

Comment: By the way, your code works perfectly if you use ``np.sin`` and ``np.cos`` NumPy functions instead of their TensorFlow counterparts.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Yes, I tried with NumPy and it worked fine. I'm just wondering why it won't work when I use TensorFlow functions. Seems strange to me, but perhaps there is a detail that I don't know of.